# Ожидание ответа от пользователя Телеграмм бот на python

Tags: python, telebot

Пишу банальную программу для записи дел в ToDo, и при вводе задачи без конкретной даты хочу спросить у пользователя "На какую дату поставить задачу?"

После этого вопроса бот не дожидается ответа, и проскакивает  `date = message.text`, принимая за ответ предыдущее сообщение, и получается в итоге что-то такое "Задача Work добавлен на дату /add Work". Как сделать так, чтобы бот дождался ответа и не проскакивал?

Вот код:

```
    @bot.message_handler(commands = ["add", "random"])
def add_random(message):
    content = message.text.split(maxsplit = 1)
    if content[0] == "/add": #mesage.text -> /add <date> <task> || /add <task>
        command = message.text.split(maxsplit = 2)
        if len(command) == 3:
            date = command[1].lower()
            task = command[2]
            add_todo(date, task)
            text = "Задача " +  task + " добавлен на дату " + date
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)
        elif len(command) == 2:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "На какую дату поставить задачу??")
            date = message.text
            task = command[1]
            add_todo(date, task)
            text = "Задача " +  task + " добавлен на дату " + date
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)
    elif content[0] == "/random":
        date = "сегодня"
        task = random.choice(random_task)``
        add_todo(date, task)
        text = "Задача " + task + " добавлен на дату " + date
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Отслеживать ввод даты юзером нужно в отдельном хэндлере, при этом зная, что он вводит именно дату. Делают это при помощи машины состояний - FSM

Вот пример из репозитория вашей библиотеки
https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py